# Hide URL through htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Perhaps this is impossible to achieve but this is what I would like:

Keep URL the same but load page from alternative site.
So MY DOMAIN is what is the input URL in my browser.
The website is loaded through SITE DOMAIN with that specific URL
But MY DOMAIN needs to stay visible and not the long SITE DOMAIN URL

With below settings I see the full URL of SITE DOMAIN but I need to keep it at MY DOMAIN. So the full SITE DOMAIN URL needs to be hidden and only show the short MY DOMAIN.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(MY DOMAIN)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(MY DOMAIN)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://(SITE DOMAIN)/cms/?option=com_content&view=article&id=150&Itemid=516" [R=301,NC,L]
```

---

EDIT:

So to be clear about my question:

example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
etc

Always need to show as display.org

But actually loads this page: http://(SITEDOMAIN)/cms/?option=com_content&view=article&id=150&Itemid=516